# fixed width table containing 100% width image - border right missing

Tags: email, border

I'm creating a responsive HTML email. At larger viewports my table is fixed width at 600px. Inside the table are 100% width images with 1px borders. In some email clients the right hand border is not showing. I presume this is because 100% width, plus 2px is more than 600px? How do I overcome this?

My images have display:block (if that is of interest). I've tried box-sizing:border-box but it doesn't seem to work... do I add this style to the image or the table, or both, where do I add it to my code?

Thanks for any help

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I'm yet to try this myself, but one of these should work for you. It is a fluid technique that will work (hopefully) in any email client on any size viewport:

```
<!-- Simple - but will have the image area set as the border color (black) when image is not loaded -->
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" bgcolor="#000000" style="padding:1px;">
      <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" width="100%" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br><br>

<!-- Setting a background color in a nested table to hide border color -->
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" bgcolor="#000000" style="padding:1px;">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" width="100%" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```